# Visual Studio 2015 crash everytime when changing the hosting web app type

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-api-apps

I'm trying to do a sample Azure API app service in Visual Studio 2015. I was following a video tutorial from Youtube and created a sample from Azure API App template. I added a controller class returning a time and uncommented SwaggerConfig.cs to enable SwaggerUI. After building this project, I tried to publish as API app to Azure by clicking on Change Type. The Visual Studio hangs and then restarts. I tried clean and publish but this is occuring every time. Am I missing anything. I am new to Azure and Visual Studio. Does anyone go through a similar scenario or have any suggestions on this please.
[VSCrash.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImzB.png)

Comment: experiencing the exact same issue, did you solve it in the meantime?

Comment: No. I tried a workaround now. Created api app in azure and selecting in the publish box. This is working now.

Comment: worked perfectly fine, thank you :)